# Storing null values in avro files

Tags: java, avro, avro-tools

I have some json data that looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1998983092,
    "name": "Test Name 1",
    "type": "search string",
    "creationDate": "2017-06-06T13:49:15.091+0000",
    "lastModificationDate": "2017-06-28T14:53:19.698+0000",
    "lastModifiedUsername": "testuser@test.com",
    "lockedQuery": false,
    "lockedByUsername": null
  }
```

I am able to add the lockedQuery null value to a GenericRecord object without issue.

```
GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
if(json.isNull("lockedQuery")){
    record.put("lockedQuery", null);
}
```

However, later when I attempt to write that GenericRecord object to an avro file I get a null pointer exception.

```
File file = new File("~/test.arvo");
DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(datumWriter);
dataFileWriter.create(schema, file);
for(GenericRecord record: masterList) {
    dataFileWriter.append(record); // NULL POINTER HERE
}
```

When I run that code I get the following exception. Any tips on how to process a null value into an Avro file much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null of boolean in field lockedQuery of 
com.mydomain.test1.domain.MyAvroRecord
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null of boolean in field lockedQuery of 
com.mydomain.test1.domain.MyAvroRecord
at com.mydomain.avro.App.main(App.java:198)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null of boolean in field lockedQuery of 
com.mydomain.test1.domain.MyAvroRecord
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:308)
```

EDIT: here is the MyAvroRecord

```
public class MyAvroRecord {
    long id;
    String name;
    String type;
    Date timestamp;
    Date lastModifcationDate;
    String lastModifiedUsername;
    Boolean lockedQuery;
```

Comment: It would probably help to have the definition of `MyAvroRecord`. I'm not particularly an Avro specialist, but in general in Java you cannot store `null` in a `boolean` (lower case) field, as it is a primitive. If you want to store a null in a boolean, you have to use `Boolean` (upper case), which is an Object and can be null.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the member definitions from MyAvroRecord. The schema file matches the types. I was using boolean and switch to Boolean objects but still have the same null pointer. When I store "false" as a default value the error goes away but I still cannot use null with an object based Boolean.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To be able to set Avro field to `null` you should allow this in Avro schema, by adding `null` as one of the possible types of the field. Take a look on example from Avro documentation:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "fields" : [
    {"name": "userId", "type": "long"},              // mandatory field
    {"name": "userName", "type": ["null", "string"]} // optional field 
  ]
}
```

here `userName` is declared as composite type which could be either `null` or `string`. This kind of definition allows to set `userName` field to null. As contrast `userId` can only contain long values, hence attempt to set `userId` to null will result in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: How can it be done in Java interface without using schema file?

Comment: You can do that using the SchemaBuilder by setting the type of the field as follows

`.type(SchemaBuilder.unionOf().nullType().and().stringType().endUnion())`

Answer (score 7):

I have this issue too and now resolved it.

I found `@Nullable` annotation in [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/Nullable.html) to declare the field is nullable.

So, in this example, we should

```
import org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable;

public class MyAvroRecord {
    long id;
    String name;
    String type;
    Date timestamp;
    Date lastModifcationDate;
    String lastModifiedUsername;
    @Nullable
    Boolean lockedQuery;
}
```